# sorting mysql with adding browser-adress-information (php)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I create a table and use the `<th>` to sort the different columns. To do this I use

```
<th><a href='?order=jahr&&sort=$sort'>Jahr</a></th>";
<th><a href='?order=kw&&sort=$sort'>Woche</a></th>";
<th><a href='?order=beschreibung&&sort=$sort'>Beschreibung</a></th>
```

which flips depending on the actual setting. If I sort by "Beschreibung" the result is ordered by "Beschreibung" and within by the "id".

How can I submit a sort for multiple columns? I want by clicking on "Woche" the result being sorted by Woche DESC and Jahr DESC.

I tried to insert instructions like

```
<a href='?order=kw&&sort=$sort&&order=jahrw&&sort=DESC'>
```

which results in getting the table sorted by the last "instruction" and not by both.

Comment: A database is used to select data, there is no need to query it to sort data when javascript can do that just fine. Take a look at DataTables for examples, 2 lines of code and you have an all you can want table.

Comment: What's with the double &s?

Comment: `sort` could be a SQL string perfectly fine, but passing the SQL statement in the URL is extremely dangerous because of SQL injection attacks. I would define a new `sort` type of parameter, something like `&sort=-woche,jahr` (where `-` means DESC) and create the SQL statement by hand. EDIT: And, yeah... just like @MrLister, what's with the double ampersands?

Comment: Thanks for the help. A link with several && get only the last pair of sort-order back. I solved it by replacing the column-name by &and; and &or; as buttons and have the multiple order-sort defined in a if(isset($_POST...). Works fine, maybe not the best way ;-)